# condição no onclick

Tags: onclick

Pretendo criar uma condição no `onclick` do botão inserir na base de dados.

Tenho as seguintes funções:

Função de Inserir:

```
function inserir_registo()
{

    var dadosajax = {
        'Tipo' : $("#Tipo").val(),
        'Prioridade' : $("#Prioridade").val(),
        'Email' : $("#Email").is(":checked") ? $("#Email").val() : '',
        'Para' : $("#Para").val(),
        'Assunto' : $("#Assunto").val(),
        'Conteudo' : $("#Conteudo").val(),
        'De' : $("#De").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: './inseriralerta',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){

        },
        success: function(data)
        { 
        $('#formulario')[0].reset();
        }
    });
}
```

Função de verificar campo:

```
function validarFormulario(){
    var myform = document.forms['formulario'] || document.formulario;
    if(myform.Tipo.value == "0" || myform.Tipo.selectedIndex == 0){
        alert('Campo Obrigatório!');
    }else{
        myform.submit();
    }
}
```

Botão:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" onclick="if(validarFormulario() == 'OK') inserir_registo();">Enviar</button>
```

Então o problema é que só pretendo que execute a função `inserir_registo();` no caso de esta função `validarFormulario();` verificar que o campo está preenchido, se não estiver não executa a função `inserir_registo();`

HTML:

```
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="POST">
       <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col_half1">
          <label>Tipo de Alerta</label>
          <div class="input_field">
            <select name="Tipo" id="Tipo">
            <option></option>
      <?php        
         $sql = "SELECT Discricao FROM raddb.TipoAlertas WHERE Id IN ('1','2','7')";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['Discricao'].'">'.$ln['Discricao'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
    </select>
          </div>
        </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
     <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" onclick="if(validarFormulario() == 'OK') inserir_registo();">Enviar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Faltou dizer qual o erro ou dificuldade que tem e tbm inserir o Html do form.

Comment: @LeAndrade o problema não é inserir, porque insere. O problema é no onclick do botão inserir `onclick="if(validarFormulario() == 'OK') inserir_registo();"`onde só pretendo que insira no caso de o campo estar preenchido. Da forma que está ele verifica que o campo está por preencher mas insere na mesma.

Comment: O que disse acima foi para descrever qual sua dificuldade e postar o Html do form junto com a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, se entendi direito o que faltou aí para validar o campo e enviar o registro foi chamar a função **inserir_registro** no `else`, ou seja, se o campo estiver válido:

```js
var myform = document.forms['formulario'] || document.formulario;

function validarFormulario(){
    if(myform.Tipo.value == "0" || myform.Tipo.selectedIndex == 0){
        alert('Campo Obrigatório!');
    }else{
        inserir_registo()             // se o campo estiver válido insere o registro
    }
}

function inserir_registo() {
  myform.submit()                     // apenas para o exemplo
  
  /* var dadosajax = {
     'Tipo' : $("#Tipo").val(),
     .... 
  */   
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="POST">
  <select name="Tipo" id="Tipo">
    <option value="0">Vazio</option>
    <option value="1">Teste 1</option>
    <option value="2">Teste 2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="validarFormulario()">Enviar</button>
<form>
```

Comment: é isso mesmo que precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Para que seja uma codição válida, acredito que você tenha que retornar algo na `function validarFormulario`.

```
function validarFormulario(){
    var myform = document.forms['formulario'] || document.formulario;
    if(myform.Tipo.value == "0" || myform.Tipo.selectedIndex == 0){
        alert('Campo Obrigatório!');
    }else{
        myform.submit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Depois, é só verificar se essa função retornará true ou não no botão.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" onclick="if(validarFormulario() === true) inserir_registo();">Enviar</button>
```

Você pode até omitir o `=== true`.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" onclick="if(validarFormulario()) inserir_registo();">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: insere na mesma no final da verificação